# PHP: Divide a string into parts, and put it into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, divide

my name is Gabriel, it's my first post/question in this BIG community.
First, i'm from Argentina, so my english isn't the best.

My problem is the next, guess that I have this string in my php file:

```
<?php
  $exampleString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
?>
```

Now, I want to know if it's possible to divide the string by **coma**, and put it into an array.

I'm new in PHP so I'm not sure at all about the functions.

**Thanks to everyone!**

```
Edit
```

What should I do if the separator is **[** 1 **]** **[** 2 **]** **[** 3 **]** **[** 4 **]** instead of a **coma**?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php. Not my downvote but there are a number of other ways to do this in PHP, `explode`, `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is! It's a little function called [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and it makes the array for you!

```
$exampleString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
$array = explode(',', $exampleString);
```

What it does is simple, you specify what you want to "explode" on (`,`), and the source string (`$exampleString`) and it works it's magic.

Comment: So, the function 'explode()', uses the first parameter to filter the string, in this case, the coma, and the second parameter, the string to divide. I'm right?

Comment: @GabrielGomez Exactly right :). This is from the [manual for explode](http://php.net/explode) -> `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )`. So `$delimiter` is what you're splitting on, and `$string` is your string !